# Auto adjusting <p> tag class according to the input given

Tags: html, css, chat

I have a speech bubble class which i'm using to show message in a chat box when the user sends it through my chat client.The user enters in the input field but if the user input goes greater than the height or width of the bubble, the message gets out of the bubble.I want to expand the bubble size according to the message given by the user. Any help?

[image]

CSS code :

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 66px;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #1e88e5;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

  .bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 41px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 11px 0;
    border-color: #1e88e5 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `min-width: 200px;` and `min-height: 66px;` and `display: inline-block;` so that the bubbles display properly.

I also added a `margin-bottom: 25px;` so that they have a space between them.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t9zb3uy/).

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t9zb3uy/1/) that handles long one-word texts. It breaks the word (`word-wrap: break-word`).

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Use `min-width` instead of `width`
Same for `height`

It is also good to set `max-width` and `overflow:hidden` for the case some enters long line without spaces.

Comment: can I ask 1 more question?

Comment: overflow:hidden hides the text entered but i want it to go to the next line if the user enters a long line

Comment: Why use `overflow: hidden` and hide text when you can wrap it?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is only for case if someone enters lo-o-ong line without spaces (or comma, or dot - i.e. unwrappable)